# Passing a structure to a function

Tags: c, function, structure

So I am having a problem when compiling this program, I just can't get it to work, I mean if I put the `inputstudent()` code inside the `main()`, it is much easier but I have to place the code in a function, `inputstudent()` and call in from the `main()`. I know it sounds very easy but I can't get it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student
{
    char surname[50];
    int age;
    char oname[50];
    char address[50];
};
void displaystudent();
void inputstudent();

int main(){
    struct student s;
    inputstudent(s);
    displaystudent(s);

    return 0;
}
void inputstudent(struct student s){
    printf("Enter the surname: ");
    scanf("%s",s.surname);
    printf("Enter the other name: ");
    scanf("%s",s.oname);
    printf("Enter the age: ");
    scanf("%d",&s.age);
    printf("Enter the address: ");
    scanf("%s",s.address);    
}
void displaystudent(struct student s)
{
    printf("Surname: %s \n",s.surname);
    printf("Oname: %s \n",s.oname);
    printf("Age: %d \n",s.age);
    printf("Address: %s",s.address);
}
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly

Comment: What does *"can't get it to work"* mean? What is the problem?

Comment: `void inputstudent(struct student s)` -> `void inputstudent(struct student *s)`, and `scanf("%s",s.surname);` -> `scanf("%s",s->surname);` etc.

Comment: You might like to try the approach(es) proposed here: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Use pointer like `inputstudent(&s);`

Comment: what others mean is that doing like you're doing you're updating a copy of your struct, but not the struct of the main program.

Comment: well when i input the names,age and address, it doesn't give me what i typed. i gives me random numbers and characters

Comment: also, why forward declaring function prototypes _without_ arguments? move the function definitions above the main, it'll be safer.

Comment: @alk ah, yes.  I remove that.

Comment: Argument passing is by value, not by reference, in C.

Comment: @IanTwy please read the comments and act accordingly. You have all the info here. The alternative is to read a good C book of course...

Comment: @Jean-Francois Fabre, will do. And thx everyone here who are helping me, i think i can do it now.

Answer (score 7):

In C parameters are passed by value, so any modifications made to a parameter inside the function will be *local* modifications.

Lets have a look at following code snippet which is basically a very simple version of what you're trying to do:

```
void GetNumber(int number)
{
   printf("Type a number:\n");
   scanf("%d", &number);   // modifies the local variable `number`?
}
...
int n = 0;
GetNumber(n);
```

Now what is the value of `n` right after the call to `GetNumber`?

Well it's not the number the user has typed, but it's still 0, that is the value `n` contained prior to the call to `GetNumber`.

What you need is this:

```
void GetNumber(int *pnumber)
{
   printf("Type a number:\n");
   scanf("%d", pnumber);  // modifies the value pointed by the pointer pnumber
}
...
int n = 0;
GetNumber(&n);  // &n is the memory address of the variable n
```

You need to read the chapter dealing with pointers in your C textbook.

**Other less important problem**

Your prototypes

```
void displaystudent();
void inputstudent();
```

don't match the corresponding functions.

Answer (score 5):

You are passing your `struct` by value, that's why the function is not modifying it. You should change your function that is intended to modify the `struct` to take a `struct` pointer as argument:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct student {
    char surname[50];
    int age;
    char oname[50];
    char address[50];
};

void displaystudent(struct student s);
void inputstudent(struct student *s);

int main() {
    struct student s;
    inputstudent(&s);
    displaystudent(s);
    return 0;
}

void inputstudent(struct student *s) {

    printf("Enter the surname: ");
    scanf("%s", s->surname);
    printf("Enter the other name: ");
    scanf("%s", s->oname);
    printf("Enter the age: ");
    scanf("%d", &s->age);
    printf("Enter the address: ");
    scanf("%s", s->address);

}

void displaystudent(struct student s) {
    printf("Surname: %s \n", s.surname);
    printf("Oname: %s \n", s.oname);
    printf("Age: %d \n", s.age);
    printf("Address: %s", s.address);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want the changes that you make to the structure variable `s` inside `inputstudent()` to be reflected back to the original variable. In that case you need to pass the address of the variable to the function instead of its value.

If you pass the *value* of `s` to the function instead of its address, a new copy of `s` would be made inside `inputstudent()` and the values would be read into this copy while the `s` in `main()` remains unchanged.

To solve this you give `inputstudent()` a pointer to the `s` in `main()` and make `inputstudent()` use this address while reading the data. In this way the changes made for the variable in `inputstudent()` will be reflected back to the `s` in `main()`.

Call the function like

```
inputstudent(&s);
```

And to access members of a structure variable using a pointer to it, you use the `->` operator instead of the `.` operator.

```
void inputstudent(struct student *s){
    printf("Enter the surname: ");
    scanf("%s",s->surname);
    printf("Enter the other name: ");
    scanf("%s",s->oname);
    printf("Enter the age: ");
    scanf("%d",&s->age);
    printf("Enter the address: ");
    scanf("%s",s->address);
}
```

Also, an address possibly involves white spaces in which `scanf()` won't do. You could use `fgets()` for that.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Michael Walz, use pointers in order to modify structure in function calls. Moreover your function signature and definition does not match that's why compiler is complaining:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student {
    char surname[50];
    int age;
    char oname[50];
    char address[50];
};
void displaystudent(struct student* pStudent);
void inputstudent(struct student* pStudent);

int main() {
    struct student aStudent;
    inputstudent(&aStudent);
    displaystudent(&aStudent);

    return 0;
}
void inputstudent(struct student* pStudent){

    printf("Enter the surname: ");
    scanf("%s", pStudent->surname);
    printf("Enter the other name: ");
    scanf("%s", pStudent->oname);
    printf("Enter the age: ");
    scanf("%d", &pStudent->age);
    printf("Enter the address: ");
    scanf("%s", pStudent->address);

}
void displaystudent(struct student* pStudent)
{
    printf("Surname: %s \n", pStudent->surname);
    printf("Oname: %s \n", pStudent->oname);
    printf("Age: %d \n", pStudent->age);
    printf("Address: %s", pStudent->address);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can't use `struct student s` as parameter in `inputstudent()`. It is just a value copy.
You should use pointer as parameter.
As:

```
void inputstudent(struct student* s)
{...}

int main(){
    struct student s;
    inputstudent(&s);
    displaystudent(s);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You aren't telling the whole story.

Answer (score -2):

There are basically two causes for your problem.

1. Function declarations don't have any parameters.
2. The structure is passed by value instead of reference to `inputstudent` function.

You can solve both of them by changing the function prototypes in both declaration and definition to

```
void displaystudent(struct student s);
void inputstudent(struct student &s);
```

Comment: Function prototype not having parameters shouldn't be a problem. No parameter means any number of parameters but if it were `void inputstudent(void)` it means no parameters are allowed.

Comment: There is no passing by reference in C, this is not a C++ question.